# Prolog stack limit exceeded

Tags: prolog

Need help!!

I was designing a knowledge base to identify (mulberry or strawberry) based on the 3 parameters(Temp, Humid, Smoist; each has 3 category, high, medium, low), but I am out of idea what is wrong.
The idea here was to use the training set as the knowledge base to identify a new test set to output either mulberry or strawberry.
Here's the code:

```
% Training set (facts)
mulberry(high, high, low).
mulberry(high, high, high).
mulberry(high, medium, low).
mulberry(medium, high, high).
mulberry(medium, medium, low).

mulberry(M_temp, M_humid, M_smoist):-
    mulberry(M_temp, _, _);
    mulberry(_, M_humid, _);
    mulberry(_, _, M_smoist).

strawberry(low, low, high).
strawberry(low, medium, low).
strawberry(low, medium, high).

strawberry(S_temp, S_humid, S_smoist):-
    strawberry(S_temp, _, _);
    strawberry(_, S_humid, _);
    strawberry(_, _, S_smoist).

condition(Temp, Humid, Smoist):-
    mulberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Mulberry"), nl;
    strawberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Strawberry"), nl.

% Test set (queries)
% condition(low, low, low)
% condition(high, medium, high)
% condition(high, low, low)
% condition(high, low, high)
```

It comes out with error for query: ?-condition(low, low, low)

```
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1.0Gb, global: 20Kb, trail: 0Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 6,708,607, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 6,708,600
ERROR:   Probable infinite recursion (cycle):
ERROR:     [6,708,607] user:mulberry(low, _5210, _5212)
ERROR:     [6,708,606] user:mulberry(low, _5232, _5234)
```

Comment: A call to `mulberry(low, _, _)` (so with two free variables), will result in another call `mulberry(low, _, _)` (with two new variables), per last clause of the `mulberry/3` predicate.

Comment: Reading your code, I don't understand what it should do. Can you explain or demonstrate?

Comment: My idea was to make the training set (mulberry(low, low, high), strawberry(...)...) as a knowledge base and use it to identify new set of data that is not in the training set(low, low, low). @TA_intern

Comment: "To identify new set of data...", your code is not doing that at all. If you want the fact base mulberry/3 or strawberry/3 to be enriched with new data, you need an asserta/assertz !

Answer (score 1):

First, a very important style issue:

```
condition(Temp, Humid, Smoist):-
    mulberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Mulberry"), nl;
    strawberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Strawberry"), nl.
```

This is a bad way of formatting your code. When one sees a block of identically indented Prolog code, the usual expectation is that each goal ends with `,` (and the last one with `.`). Having some lines terminated with `;` is something that is *very* easy to overlook. And `;` has *dramatic* semantic effects that should be very visible in the code.

A better way of formatting this would be something like:

```
condition(Temp, Humid, Smoist):-
    (   mulberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
        write("Class: Mulberry"), nl
    ;   strawberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
        write("Class: Strawberry"), nl ).
```

(There are other, similar ways. The important point common to them is that indentation makes clear that there is a choice going on -- similar to how in other programming languages one would indent the branches of a statement like `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`.)

An even better way of formatting acknowledges the fact that disjunction is *so* special in Prolog that there is an even more special syntax for it:

```
condition(Temp, Humid, Smoist):-
    mulberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Mulberry"), nl.
condition(Temp, Humid, Smoist):-
    strawberry(Temp, Humid, Smoist),
    write("Class: Strawberry"), nl.
```

As for your issue, with this definition:

```
mulberry(M_temp, M_humid, M_smoist):-
    mulberry(M_temp, _, _);
    mulberry(_, M_humid, _);
    mulberry(_, _, M_smoist).
```

When you call this as `mulberry(low, low, low)`, this will try to prove that by calling `mulberry(low, _, _)`, which will call `mulberry(low, _, _)`, etc. This will go on like this without terminating and essentially overflow the stack.

I *think* that when you write:

```
mulberry(high, high, low).
mulberry(high, high, high).
```

you want to express something like "we have previous knowledge that the properties `high, high, low` match `mulberry`".

And when you write:

```
mulberry(M_temp, M_humid, M_smoist):-
    mulberry(M_temp, _, _);
    mulberry(_, M_humid, _);
    mulberry(_, _, M_smoist).
```

I think you want to express "given a new observation, if it matches the known properties for `mulberry`, then `mulberry` is a possible classification".

Known facts vs. classification of new observations are different concepts. They should be represented using different predicates. Something like:

```
%% knowledge base
fruit_properties(mulberry, high, high, low).
fruit_properties(mulberry, high, high, high).
fruit_properties(mulberry, high, medium, low).
fruit_properties(mulberry, medium, high, high).
fruit_properties(mulberry, medium, medium, low).

fruit_properties(strawberry, low, low, high).
fruit_properties(strawberry, low, medium, low).
fruit_properties(strawberry, low, medium, high).

%% classification of an observation
observation_classification(M_temp, M_humid, M_smoist, Fruit) :-
    fruit_properties(Fruit, M_temp, M_humid, M_smoist).
```

Some examples of classifying some (even partial) observations:

```
?- observation_classification(high, medium, low, Fruit).
Fruit = mulberry.

?- observation_classification(_, medium, low, Fruit).
Fruit = mulberry ;
Fruit = mulberry ;
Fruit = strawberry.

?- observation_classification(_, low, _, Fruit).
Fruit = strawberry.
```